# Using Caret with SparkR?

Tags: r, r-caret, sparkr

Perhaps somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373510/how-to-do-cross-validation-in-sparkr), it doesn't seem like SparkR dataframes are compatible with the caret package.

When I try to train my model, I get the following error:

```
    Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
  cannot coerce class "structure("SparkDataFrame", package = "SparkR")" to a data.frame
```

Is there any way around this?  Below's a reproducible example using iris:

```
#load libraries
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
set.seed(42)

#point R session to Spark
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "your/spark/installation/here")
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))

#load SparkR
library(SparkR)

#initialize Spark context
sc <- sparkR.init(master = "local",sparkEnvir = list(spark.driver.memory="2g"))

#initialize SQL context
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

train2 <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, iris)

#train the model
model <- train(Species ~ Sepal_Length + Petal_Length,
               data = train2,
               method = "rf",
               trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)

)
```

Again, any way around this?  If not, what's the most straightforward path to machine learning with SparkR?

Comment: this is not possible.

Comment: @mtoto I think I've definitely discovered this -- but what are some alternatives to achieving machine learning with SparkR?  Are there any?

Comment: yes: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html#machine-learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use `caret`'s training methods on `SparkDataFrames`, as you've discovered. You can however use `Spark-ml`'s algorithms, for instance to train a random forest classifier, using `SparkR::spark.randomForest`:

```
#train the model
model <- spark.randomForest(train2,
                            type="classification",  
                            Species ~ Sepal_Length + Petal_Length,
                            maxDepth = 5,
                            numTrees = 100)

summary(model)
```